# Cómo evitar que composer revise todas las versiones

Tags: php, composer

No es un problema en sí, es algún dato de configuración y es más bien por ahorrar tiempo en la actualización de las dependencias.

El tema es que cada vez que *composer* actualiza las dependencias revisa todas las versiones de cada repositorio.

```
Loading composer repositories with package
informReading composer.json of user/repository (0.0.1)  

Loading composer repositories with package
informReading composer.json of user/repository (0.0.2)

Loading composer repositories with package
informReading composer.json of user/repository (0.0.3)
...
```

> Me pasa solo con los repositorios privados personales.

Algunos repositorios tienen pocas versiones por que son nuevos, pero otros tienen ya un número considerado de versiones y esto ralentiza bastante la actualización.

La configuración del composer del repositorio que se solicita es bastante básica:

```
{
    "name":"user/repository",
    "type": "library",
    "description":"Descripción",
    "authors":[
        {
            "name":"Nombre",
            "email":"email",
            "role":"role"
        }
    ],
    "require":{
        "php":"^5.6 || ^7.0"
    },
    "autoload":{
        "psr-4":{
            "Module\\":"src/Module/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "./Module.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

La configuración del composer que hace la actualización:

```
{
    "name":"user/application",
    "description":"Descripción",
    "require":{
        "php":">=7.0",
        "user/repository":"1.*"
    },
    "repositories":[
        { "type": "vcs", "url": "git@github.com:user/repos.git" }
    ]
}
```

Hace algún tiempo leí algo al respecto, pero lo he buscado de nuevo y no consigo dar con la solución.

#### La pregunta:

**¿Cómo se puede evitar que composer revise todas las versiones cuando actualiza las dependencias?**

Answer (score 1):

Buenas para que no revise las versiones debes poner el numero de la versión que quieres utilizar por ejemplo:

```
"require":{
    "php":7.0"
},
```

Esto indica que solo vas a utilizar la versión 7.0 de php y una vez instalado no buscara nuevas versiones.

Aquí tienes un enlace a la documentación de [Versiones en composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md).

Estás poniendo en tu composer:

```
"user/repository":"1.*" //esto indica que va desde la versión 1.0 hasta la versión 2.0
```

Para trabajar con versiones en repositotios tienes que utilizar Alias.

Aquí tienes un enlace a la documentación de [Alias en composer.](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md)

Comment: Gracias por responder. He actualizado la pregunta y probado a limitar las versiones. Incluso con _dev-master_ que según el enlace, apunta solo a esa rama, por lo que no debería comprobar versiones del repositorio entiendo. Y sigue comprobando todas las versiones.